# Dynamically sort data only after specific cell data

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, dynamic, range

I am looking to sort data after a dynamic row is created with specific text in one cell in the A column. I am able to set up the condition where the data is only sorted once the cell is located, but I am struggling with then specifying to only apply the sort to the rows beyond that location. Here is what I have tried, attempting to sort only the data one row below where Cell 8 does not equal Cell 9 and beyond for column C:

```
Dim intl As Range
Dim rSortRangez As Range
Dim iRowz As Integer, iColz As Integer
Dim cus As Range

Set intl = shtDest.Range("C8")

iRowz = intl.Row
iColz = intl.Column
Set rSortRangez = sheets("Sheet1").Range("A8", "P99")
Set cus = intl.Offset(1, 0)
Do

For Each intl In rSortRangez
If intl <> intl.Offset(1, 0) Then
rSortRangez.Sort _
    Key1:=sheets("Sheet1").Range("cus"), Order1:=xlDescending, _
    Header:=xlNo, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, _
    DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, DataOption3:=xlSortNormal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the vba Range.Sort method.

It can be used as follows:

```
Dim customSortRangeString As String
customSortRangeString = "C1:E5" 'enter in whatever you want

'key1 is the column that you will be sorting based on the first time.
'order1 is the order that it will sort the first time.
'header tells excel that the first row contains headers.

'Note: there are also key2 and key3 (as well as an order for each) allowing you to have multiple
'search criteria.

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet("YOUR WORKSHEET HERE").Range(customSortRangeString).Sort key1:=Range("C2"), _
          order1:=xlAccending, header:=xlYes
```

More information on the sort method can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort)

**UPDATE - 5/9/19**: Added information for a dynamic sort range based on criteria provided in this answer's comments.

```
Private Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim totalRow As Integer
    Dim startSortRow As Integer
    Dim sortRange As String
    Dim sortKey As String

    'Setting both the workbook and sheet to variables to make them easier to use.
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("YOUR WORK SHEET")

    'getting the total number of rows we may have to loop through to find the appropreate cell.
    totalRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'loops through the rows
    For a = 1 To totalRow
        'checks if the previous cell does not equal the current cell
        If ws.Range("C" & a).Value <> ws.Range("C" & a - 1) Then
            'if above statement is true, set the startSortRow to the value of a and exit the loop
            startSortRow = a
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'Create the sort range string
    sortRange = "A" & startSortRow & ":P100"

    'Create the sort key
    sortKey = "C" & startSortRow

    'Sort based on the values found above
    ws.Range(sortRange).Sort key1:=Range(sortKey), order1:=xlAccending, Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

This should work as expected with the dynamic sort range. (Have not tested)

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm still struggling with setting the range dynamically so only the data past a certain point is sorted. The example of "C1:E5" assumes the data will always be in the same cells. Do you have any suggestions to overcome this? Thank you.

Comment: Will the range that you want to sort always be at the bottom? Eg. you don't want to sort C1:E5 but do want to sort E6: (end of column). Or will you have text after it that you don't want sorted as well? How dynamic is it? Is it multi dimentional (columns and rows) or only in a line? (appologies for all the questions, just want to make sure that I don't give inaccurate responses :) )

Comment: No need to apologize! I appreciate you taking the time to help me out and I'll try to be as detailed and clear as possible. The range to be sorted will always be at least A8:P100, but could start at A9, A10, etc depending on the scenario. As long as the condition is met where C8:C does not equal the previous cell in the C column, the sort applies to every cell below it applying to both rows and columns in A8:P100

Comment: Ok I have updated my answer with the information for dynamic range based on your criteria.